# Using FromSqlRaw with TPT inheritance in EF Core 7

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

We are trying to use the `FromSql` method in a `DbSet` of a class that implements TPT inheritance, and we are getting this error:

> Using 'FromSql' on DbSet of 'CuSimple' is not supported since 'CuSimple' is part of hierarchy and does not contain a discriminator property.

Isn't it possible at all to use `FromSql` along with TPT? Can anybody help with any alternatives so that we can apply serialized criteria to our TPT `DbSet` (we also tried to apply expressions directly to the `DbSet`, but got stuck trying to create a multi-column join expression...).

Thanks and regards